# Runtime error "cannot find module ionic-native"

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am a new to ionic i am developing a simple application my code build successfully but after that giving me the error "Cannot find module ionic-native"

I had used the following code to develop the sample app
https://github.com/seeschweiler/iongithub

and getting this error
http://image.prntscr.com/image/3b9012e75bb84c24912987c1e41dfbba.png

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Please see this.Maybe helped to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43583422/1077309

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: you can see my package.json in the this link  : http://prntscr.com/f0hxvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run the code and it is working fine without any error, so I suggest to delete the `node_modules` directory and run `npm i` in the CMD or terminal

Comment: when i run npm i command automatically node_module directory added